# JPA GeneratedValue generated an already existent Id

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I am developing a Spring application that uses JPA. Specifically, to generate the ids of my entities I am using the `@GeneratedValue` annotation. For example:

```java
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  
  private String someField;

  // Getters and Setters...
}
```

The thing is, I am preloading data into the database. For example, in `someFile.sql` I have regular `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO some_entity (id, some_field) VALUES (1, 'foo');
INSERT INTO some_entity (id, some_field) VALUES (2, 'bar');
...
```

Then, I just insert the data using the mysql command line client:

```
mysql someDB < someFile.sql
```

The problem is, when a try to persist a new entity using JPA, the first id which will be assigned is `1`. However, that id was already being used by one of the entities I had preloaded to the database. This way, I am getting a duplicate key error:

> 2020-07-04 16:08:42.365 ERROR 847 --- [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

I have considered using an initial value with a `@SequenceGenerator`. However, this approach could lead to having to change the code if the number of initial values I want to preload increases.

Any ideas on a different approach?

Comment: From the log, i see you are using Hibernate as persistence provider. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simplest solution is to make the script itself establish the correct value for the next generated id.

If you're using Hibernate <5 or Hibernate 5 with `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false`, your setup will have resulted in `id` being an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. In that case simply add

```
ALTER TABLE some_entity AUTO_INCREMENT = <last_inserted_id>
```

at the end of your script. Or, better still, try to get rid of the hardcoded id values altogether, if possible. You can retrieve the last inserted id using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and use that value for setting foreign key columns in dependent rows.

If, on the other hand, you're using Hibernate 5 without any special config, you should find a `hibernate_sequence` table in your schema, which stores the next generated id to be used by Hibernate. You will need to add sth like:

```
UPDATE hibernate_sequence SET next_val= <max_inserted_id_for_any_table_plus_one>
```

As a side note, [if you're using the latter approach by accident, you might want to switch to the former](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-should-not-use-the-auto-jpa-generationtype-with-mysql-and-hibernate/).

Comment: I ended up switching the generation strategy to `IDENTITY`, which seems to work (the id is now `AUTO_INCREMENT`). I did not know the `AUTO` strategy defauls to `TABLE` with MySQL, neither about `LAST_INSERTED_ID()`. Thank you!